# Writing my own FGSM Adversarial attack always gives zero perturbation

Tags: keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to write a simple FGSM attack on MNIST. I tried the foolbox library and it seems to work but the FGSM is very slow (perhaps because it searches for a minimum eps/perturbation which gives a different target label). I started writing my own and my code always gives me zero perturbation. I.e., if I plot the x_adversarial it is the same as x_input. I checked that the gradient computation leads all zero matrix. The computed loss function is small, but I imagine there is some gradient to this loss function. Can somebody please help me? I have been racking my head for a week now without any progress. Thanks again!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import foolbox
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Importing the required Keras modules containing model and layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

num_digits_to_classify = 10

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
# Making sure that the values are float so that we can get decimal points after division
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
# Normalizing the RGB codes by dividing it to the max RGB value.
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('Number of images in x_train', x_train.shape[0])
print('Number of images in x_test', x_test.shape[0])

def create_model_deep():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(5,5),activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten()) # Flattening the 2D arrays for fully connected layers
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(num_digits_to_classify,activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_model_deep()
model.summary()
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, epochs=10)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

########################## foolbox FGSM attack ###############################################

from keras.backend import set_learning_phase
set_learning_phase(0)
from foolbox.criteria import Misclassification

fmodel = foolbox.models.TensorFlowModel.from_keras(model, bounds=(0,1))

attack = foolbox.attacks.FGSM(fmodel, criterion=Misclassification())

fgsm_error = 0.0
for i in range(x_test.shape[0]):
    if i%1000 == 0:
        print(i)
    adversarial = attack(x_test[i],y_test[i])
    if adversarial is not None:
        adversarial = adversarial.reshape(1,28,28,1)    
        model_predictions = model.predict(adversarial)
        label = np.argmax(model_predictions)
        if label != y_test[i]:
            fgsm_error = fgsm_error + 1.0

fgsm_error = fgsm_error/x_test.shape[0]


########################## My own FGSM attack ###############################################

sess = K.get_session()
eps = 0.3

x_adv =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1,28,28,1),name="adv_example")
x_noise = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1,28,28,1),name="adv_noise")
x_input = x_test[0].reshape(1,28,28,1)
y_input = y_test[0]
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

grad = K.gradients(loss_fn(y_input,model.output), model.input)
delta = K.sign(grad[0])
x_noise = x_noise + delta
x_adv = x_adv + eps*delta
x_adv = K.clip(x_adv,0.0,1.0)

x_adv, x_noise, grad = sess.run([x_adv, x_noise, grad], feed_dict={model.input:x_input, x_adv:x_input, x_noise:np.zeros_like(x_input)})


pred = model.predict(x_adv)
```

The following code seems to work now. Please look at the comment I made below.

```py
sess = K.get_session()
eps = 0.3

i = 100
x_input = x_test[i].reshape(1,28,28,1)
y_input = y_test[i]
x_adv =  x_input
# Added noise
x_noise = np.zeros_like(x_input)

def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    target = K.one_hot(y_true,10)    
    loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(target, y_pred)
    return loss    
    #loss = K.print_tensor(loss,message='loss = ')    
    #return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

def loss_fn_sparse(y_true, y_pred):    
    loss = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss 

image = K.cast(x_input,dtype='float32')  
y_pred = model(image)
loss = loss_fn_sparse(y_input, y_pred)
grad = K.gradients(loss, image)
delta = K.sign(grad[0])
x_noise = x_noise + delta
x_adv = x_adv + eps*delta
x_adv = K.clip(x_adv,0.0,1.0)

x_adv, x_noise = sess.run([x_adv, x_noise], feed_dict={model.input:x_input})

pred = model.predict(x_adv)
```

Comment: Actually, I figures out the solution. I think the trouble was that I was mixing two things. Some places I use the Keras backend but then I define placeholders with tf.placeholder. I actually removed the tf.placeholder and do not provide them as input from feed_dict. The following code seems to work.

Comment: So the code I wrote works but is slower than foolbox library. Any reason for that? Perhaps because I'm doing things in Keras.backend which makes it slow?